# Using a Messagebox like Form with yes/no

Tags: vb.net

Hey there i like to use a nice designed Form with yes no Buttons to use it like the normal yes/no Messagebox. To be clear its not a Messagebox its a Form with a Background Picture and Label (for the Textbody) and 2 Buttons (yes / no).

But what must i do, that it opens the Form and send back the user´s choice that i can work with.

```
Messagetext = "This is the Text that is shown in the custBox"

Dim custBox As New custBox
CustBox.ShowDialog()
Select Case DialogResult
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
                'code if clicked yes
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
                'Code if clicked no
End Select
```

But i think it does not Work like this.

Comment: It should be `Select Case custBox.DialogResult`. Currently, you're using the `DialogResult` property of the _calling_ form.

Comment: As a side note, try not to use the same name of the class/form for the variable. Use something like `Dim box as new custBox`, for example.

Comment: Please add the code for `custForm` to your post.

Answer (score 1):

The `DialogResult` is the RETURN value from `ShowDialog()`, so you can do:

```
Dim cb As New custBox
Dim result As DialogResult = cb.ShowDialog()
Select Case result
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
        'code if clicked yes
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
        'Code if clicked no
End Select
```

Hopefully you're actually setting `DialogResult` in your other form, when one of the buttons is clicked:

```
' ... in your "dialog" form, Yes/No Button Handler ...
Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes ' or DialogResult.No
```

Comment: Thanks booth of you, yes i added that DialogResult. Only did the error Palestine fixed, perhabs its not that good to Code when i dont have enough sleep. In the Meaning of "See no Forest because of Trees..."
Big thanks to booth of you, have a nice new year

Comment: For the record, there's no need to handle the Click event of the Buttons and set the form's DialogResult property. You can set the DialogResult property of the Buttons in the designer. Only handle the Click event if you need to do something else as well.